# Can you please help me to get streamline plot?

Tags: differential-equations

[image: stream lines for the velocity with respect to curvature parameter]

https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cjph.2020.08.010 , this is the DOI of the paper. I have written a code to plot graph but I need to plot it with stream lines too

```
    \[Phi] = 0.6;
m = 5;
uhs = -5;
\[Zeta] = 0.7;
\[Zeta]1 = 1;
x = 0.2;
A1 = 1.02;
Ha = 0.5;
A3 = 1.1;
\[Alpha]e = 2;
\[Beta]e = 0.5;
\[Kappa] = 2.0;
t = 1.00;
h = 1 - \[Phi] (Cos[\[Pi] (x - t)])^2;
K1 = BesselK[0, m (\[Kappa] - h)];
K2 = BesselK[0, m (\[Kappa] + h)];
I1 = BesselI[0, m (\[Kappa] - h)];
I2 = BesselI[0, m (\[Kappa] + h)];
\[Psi]1 = \[Zeta]1 ((K2 - \[Zeta] K1)/(
      I1  K2 - I2 K1) (BesselI[0, m (\[Kappa] + r)]) + (\[Zeta] I1 - 
       I2)/(I1 K2 - I2 K1) (BesselK[0, m (\[Kappa] + r)]));
NDSolve[{A1 (-1/(r + \[Kappa]) u'''[r] - u''''[r] + 
        1/(\[Kappa] + r)^2 (u'[r] + 
           1)) + (uhs) (m)^2 (\[Psi]1) + (Ha)^2 ( ((A3) \[Alpha]e (1 -
           u'[r]))/(((\[Alpha]e)^2 + (\[Beta]e)^2) (r + \[Kappa])^2)) \
== 0, u[h] == 1 , u[-h] == -1, u'[h] == 1, u'[-h] == 1}, 
  u, {r, -h, h}];
P1 = Plot[Evaluate[u'[r] /. %], {r, -h, h}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(U\), \(HS\)]\)=-5"}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, FrameLabel -> {r, u}, Frame -> True, 
  ImageSize -> Large, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium], 
  Axes -> False]
```

Comment: The plots from paper seem to be symmetric, your plot of `u'[r]` isn't!

Comment: Your equation is different from the one used in the article. How did you derive your equation?

Comment: yes sir , i have added magnetic(hall effect) to the paper, so the eqn is different.  Im trying to get the countor plot for the code which i have written.

Answer (score 4):

The `Streamplot` for plot `P1`

```
sol = NDSolve[{A1 (-1/(r + κ) u'''[r] - u''''[r] +1/(κ + r)^2 (u'[r] +1)) + (uhs) (m)^2 (ψ1) + (Ha)^2 (((A3) αe (1 -u'[r]))/(((αe)^2 + (βe)^2) (r + κ)^2))== 0, u[h] == 1, u[-h] == -1, u'[h] == 1, u'[-h] == 1}, 
u, {r, -h, h}][[1]]

Show[{Plot[u'[r] /. sol, {r, -h, h}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
StreamPlot[{1, u''[r]} /. sol , {r, -h, h}, {y, 0, 2}]}, AxesLabel -> {"r","u'[r]"}]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: According to the paper referred to by the author of the topic, 'u` is a stream function.

Answer (score 2):

Store the solution of the "NDSolve" and use it in a StreamPlot:

```
sol = NDSolve[{A1 (-1/(r + κ) u'''[r] - u''''[r] + 
         1/(κ + r)^2 (u'[r] + 
            1)) + (uhs) (m)^2 (ψ1) + (Ha)^2 (((A3) αe (1 -
              u'[r]))/(((αe)^2 + (βe)^2) (r + \
κ)^2)) == 0, u[h] == 1, u[-h] == -1, u'[h] == 1, u'[-h] == 1}, 
   u, {r, -h, h}][[1]];

StreamPlot[{r, u'[r] /. sol}, {r, -h, h}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cjph.2020.08.010) `u` is a strem function, therefore, we can use `ContourPlot[]` to visualize streamlines as follows

```
\[Phi] = 0.6;
m = 5;
uhs = -5;
\[Zeta] = 0.7;
\[Zeta]1 = 1;
(*x=0.2;*)
A1 = 1.02;
Ha = 0.5;
A3 = 1.1;
\[Alpha]e = 2;
\[Beta]e = 0.5;
\[Kappa] = 2.0;
t = 1.00;
psi[xe_, ye_] := 
  Module[{x = xe, yc = ye}, h = 1 - \[Phi] (Cos[\[Pi] (x - t)])^2;
   K1 = BesselK[0, m (\[Kappa] - h)];
   K2 = BesselK[0, m (\[Kappa] + h)];
   I1 = BesselI[0, m (\[Kappa] - h)];
   I2 = BesselI[0, m (\[Kappa] + h)];
   \[Psi]1 = \[Zeta]1 ((K2 - \[Zeta] K1)/(I1 K2 - I2 K1) (BesselI[0, 
          m (\[Kappa] + r)]) + (\[Zeta] I1 - I2)/(I1 K2 - 
           I2 K1) (BesselK[0, m (\[Kappa] + r)]));
   U = NDSolveValue[{A1 (-1/(r + \[Kappa]) u'''[r] - u''''[r] + 
           1/(\[Kappa] + r)^2 (u'[r] + 
              1)) + (uhs) (m)^2 (\[Psi]1) + (Ha)^2 (((A3) \[Alpha]e \
(1 - u'[r]))/(((\[Alpha]e)^2 + (\[Beta]e)^2) (r + \[Kappa])^2)) == 0, 
      u[h] == 1, u[-h] == -1, u'[h] == 1, u'[-h] == 1}, 
     u, {r, -h, h}]; U[yc]];
```

To plot `P1` we evaluate

```
With[{x = .2}, 
 With[{h = 1 - \[Phi] (Cos[\[Pi] (x - t)])^2}, 
  P1 = Plot[Evaluate[Derivative[0, 1][psi][x, r]], {r, -h, h}, 
    PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(U\), \(HS\)]\)=-5"}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, FrameLabel -> {r, u}, Frame -> True, 
    ImageSize -> Large, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium], 
    Axes -> False]]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

To visualize streamlines we use code

```
With[{h = 1 - \[Phi] (Cos[\[Pi] (x - t)])^2}, 
 ContourPlot[Evaluate[psi[x, y]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, -h, h}, 
  Contours -> 21, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Frame -> False, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Please, pay attention that `NDSolve` cannot find solution for some `x` around border $r=\pm h$, therefore plot looks like eroded. To avoid this we use restriction `PlotRange -> {-.95, .95}`, then picture looks more smooth
[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Nice answer! Unfortunately Mathematica v12.2 only plots nearly parallel streamlines with your code. Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Luckily I have version 12.2 and can test the code to answer your question. To my surprise, the result was the same picture as with versions 13.3 shown above. Try compute again on a fresh kernel.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. With fresh kernel I get (for your last code block) the message "NDSolveValue::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable u." and Mathematica keeps on running

Comment: Now evaluation finished after some time and shows your streamplot! Where in this streamplot can I find the soultion `U[r]` which monotonically runs from -1 to 1?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Look at the `PlotLegends` bar.  It shows colors from minus one to one.:)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I realize that, but shouldn't the solution `U[r]` also be a phase line?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Generally speaking, by definition, stream function level lines called stream lines. In modern programs like `StreamPlot`, arrows are also added to these lines. Please note that in the article they used `ContourPlot`. This is how we painted in the last century. :)

Comment: Your  reference to the past century makes me think ;-) . I was thinking more about "phaseportrait"

Comment: @UlrichNeumann No it is not  "phaseportrait". This is stream plot as it is. Don't forget that `u` is a stream function. And the main property of the stream function is that the stream function is constant along any streamline - see, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_function .

Comment: Thank you for your help